# JB Custom Activity - Data Binding

Tags: journeybuilder, custom-object, databinding

unfortunately, as is often the case, the documentation is not always comprehensive. In the link about Data Binding (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/how-data-binding-works.htm) it is not specified if the system reasons in bulk or not.

In detail, does the InArguments parameter accept more than one client in the same call?

```
"inArguments": [
            {
                "contactIdentifier": "{{Contact.Key}}"
            },
            {
                "emailAddress": "{{InteractionDefaults.Email}}"
            },
            {
                "twitterHandle": "{{Contact.Default.Twitter}}"
            },
            {
                "lastLogin": "{{Contact.Attribute.Engagement.LastLogin}}"
            }

            {..}
        ]
```

When a contact enters the custom activity is it handled individually ? Or is it possible to manage a Batch of users in the same call (like for Emails) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Journey Builder processes records destined for your application on a row by row basis. You get one execute request per contact.